# Drawing tetrominos (Tetris pieces)

Tags: c++, sfml

I am having trouble creating/drawing the tetrominos (Tetris pieces), what are my options in C++ using SFML?

I tried to draw them as a convex using switch statement and giving them numbers, which didn't work because the L and J shapes are concave.

```
 ConvexShape blocks;
    blocks.setTexture(&tile);

             // block generation and shape
    default_random_engine randomGenerator(time(0));
    uniform_int_distribution<int> blocktype(0,6);
    int n = blocktype(randomGenerator);
    switch (n)
    {
        case (0): blocks.setPointCount(4);
                  blocks.setPoint(0,Vector2f(0.0f,0.0f));
                  blocks.setPoint(1,Vector2f(18.0f,0.0f));
                  blocks.setPoint(2,Vector2f(18.0f,72.0f));
                  blocks.setPoint(3,Vector2f(0.0f,72.0f));
                  break;
        case (1): blocks.setPointCount(4);
                  blocks.setPoint(0,Vector2f(0.0f,0.0f));
                  blocks.setPoint(1,Vector2f(36.0f,0.0f));
                  blocks.setPoint(2,Vector2f(36.0f,36.0f));
                  blocks.setPoint(3,Vector2f(0.0f,36.0f));
                  break;
        case (2): blocks.setPointCount(8);
                  blocks.setPoint(0,Vector2f(0.0f,0.0f));
                  blocks.setPoint(1,Vector2f(18.0f,0.0f));
                  blocks.setPoint(2,Vector2f(18.0f,18.0f));
                  blocks.setPoint(3,Vector2f(36.0f,18.0f));
                  blocks.setPoint(4,Vector2f(36.0f,36.0f));
                  blocks.setPoint(5,Vector2f(18.0f,36.0f));
                  blocks.setPoint(6,Vector2f(18.0f,54.0f));
                  blocks.setPoint(7,Vector2f(0.0f,54.0f));
                  break;
        case (3): blocks.setPointCount(8);
                  blocks.setPoint(0,Vector2f(0.0f,0.0f));
                  blocks.setPoint(1,Vector2f(18.0f,0.0f));
                  blocks.setPoint(2,Vector2f(18.0f,18.0f));
                  blocks.setPoint(3,Vector2f(36.0f,18.0f));
                  blocks.setPoint(4,Vector2f(36.0f,54.0f));
                  blocks.setPoint(5,Vector2f(18.0f,54.0f));
                  blocks.setPoint(6,Vector2f(18.0f,36.0f));
                  blocks.setPoint(7,Vector2f(0.0f,36.0f));
                  break;
        case (4): blocks.setPointCount(8);
                  blocks.setPoint(0,Vector2f(0.0f,18.0f));
                  blocks.setPoint(1,Vector2f(18.0f,18.0f));
                  blocks.setPoint(2,Vector2f(18.0f,0.0f));
                  blocks.setPoint(3,Vector2f(36.0f,0.0f));
                  blocks.setPoint(4,Vector2f(36.0f,36.0f));
                  blocks.setPoint(5,Vector2f(18.0f,36.0f));
                  blocks.setPoint(6,Vector2f(18.0f,54.0f));
                  blocks.setPoint(7,Vector2f(0.0f,54.0f));
                  break;
        case (5): blocks.setPointCount(6);
                  blocks.setPoint(0,Vector2f(0.0f,54.0f));
                  blocks.setPoint(1,Vector2f(0.0f,0.0f));
                  blocks.setPoint(2,Vector2f(18.0f,0.0f));
                  blocks.setPoint(3,Vector2f(18.0f,40.0f));
                  blocks.setPoint(4,Vector2f(36.0f,36.0f));
                  blocks.setPoint(5,Vector2f(36.0f,54.0f));
                  break;
        case (6): blocks.setPointCount(6);
                  blocks.setPoint(0,Vector2f(0.0f,0.0f));
                  blocks.setPoint(1,Vector2f(54.0f,0.0f));
                  blocks.setPoint(2,Vector2f(54.0f,18.0f));
                  blocks.setPoint(3,Vector2f(36.0f,18.0f));
                  blocks.setPoint(4,Vector2f(36.0f,36.0f));
                  blocks.setPoint(5,Vector2f(18.0f,36.0f));
                  break;
    }
```

[The L n J shape appear like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSyA6.jpg)

Comment: post what you have tried and what issues are you facing

Comment: Yes, please post the relevant code and switch statements.

Comment: @AyushGupta I added the things you requested

Comment: @MartinSand added the switch n the code

Comment: @Ayush updated the post for what you requested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, when using a library such as SFML, it's important to always remember that the library might provide you with convenient shortcuts (like `sf::CircleShape` or `sf::RectangleShape`), but you don't necessarily have to use them, especially if it exposes you something far more flexible, such as `sf::VertexArray`.

Next you'll also have to remember that there's more than one way to build your tetrominos from basic primitives.

The most obvious one here would be using triangles or quads. Let's build the T shape using quads:

```
sf::VertexArray quads(sf::Quads);

// Left piece
quads.append({{0, 0}, sf::Color::White});
quads.append({{95, 0}, sf::Color::Red});
quads.append({{95, 95}, sf::Color::Green});
quads.append({{0, 95}, sf::Color::Blue});

// Center piece
quads.append({{100, 0}, sf::Color::White});
quads.append({{195, 0}, sf::Color::Red});
quads.append({{195, 95}, sf::Color::Green});
quads.append({{100, 95}, sf::Color::Blue});

// Right piece
quads.append({{200, 0}, sf::Color::White});
quads.append({{295, 0}, sf::Color::Red});
quads.append({{295, 95}, sf::Color::Green});
quads.append({{200, 95}, sf::Color::Blue});

// Bottom piece
quads.append({{100, 100}, sf::Color::White});
quads.append({{195, 100}, sf::Color::Red});
quads.append({{195, 195}, sf::Color::Green});
quads.append({{100, 195}, sf::Color::Blue});
```

Note that `sf::Quads` is not supported on mobile platforms and you'd have to define triangles rather than quads. Also I've intentionally shortened lengths/widths of the quads by 5 to leave visible gaps.

The probably more elegant (and efficient) solution is to use a triangle fan. Since the T tetromino is a concave shape, you'll have to pick the correct starting point for your fan, i.e. one of the points making the shape concave. In other instances you might have to create a new (invisible) point specifically for this though, e.g. inside the shape.

```
sf::VertexArray triangleFan(sf::TriangleFan);

// Starting point is the bottom left corner of the center piece
triangleFan.append({{100, 100}, sf::Color::White});
triangleFan.append({{0, 100}, sf::Color::Red});
triangleFan.append({{0, 0}, sf::Color::Green});
triangleFan.append({{300, 0}, sf::Color::Blue});
triangleFan.append({{300, 100}, sf::Color::Magenta});
// The next point creates an invisible triangle just to move to the center piece
triangleFan.append({{200, 100}, sf::Color::Black});
triangleFan.append({{200, 200}, sf::Color::Cyan});
triangleFan.append({{100, 200}, sf::Color::Yellow});
```

Drawing these two shapes with a translation of `{50, 50}` or `{50, 350}` respectively results in two giant tetrominos on screen:

[image: Example Screenshot]

For your case you'd have to scale them properly of course.

If you're still having issues or want something to compile, run, and play around with, I've uploaded a [short example](https://gist.github.com/MarioLiebisch/2e86796613c6aec226eda5717371d7f6) on GitHub.

Comment: Thank you very much, but the thing is I don't really understand how vertex arrays work, can you explain please? Or you can share a link if you know a video explaining how it works

Comment: @user9135740 You can basically look at any OpenGL (or even DirectX) tutorial regarding this. The only difference is how you actually define the vertices. [Here's an example guide showcasing the various possibilities and how they work.](https://www.3dgep.com/rendering-primitives-with-opengl/#Primitives) `sf::VertexArray` is basically just a container. you could also use a `std::vector<sf::Vertex>` instead. The vertex array just also defines how the list of points is to be interpreted.

Comment: Thanks Mario that helps I'll ask again if there is confusion

Comment: @Mario Complete off-topic: how exactly did you manage to have a transparent profile picture? I've been fighting against that black square for hours and couldn't do it...

Comment: What if I use a tringle strip instead, and if I adjust the quads are they counted as one or would they still be separate?

Comment: N when using the triangle fan doesn't the invisible triangle have an effect when adding a texture and during collision?

Comment: @Quentin No idea, it's just a PNG with transparency.

Comment: @user9135740 You can use a table script or anything else. This is just for your visual representation. It shouldn't be used for collision detection. Look up Tetris logic stuff instead.

Comment: Got no idea what you just said, How does a table script work? It is a school project n now am having trouble, n what Tetris logic should I look up? Help please

Comment: @user9135740 Others have had the same problem. [Here's one example.](https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/implementing-tetris-collision-detection--gamedev-852) The basic idea is to implement the game and its logic in pure data. For example, a 2D array representing the play field (i.e. where blocks exist). The game logic shouldn't care how you draw the blocks.

Comment: @Mario it turns out avatars automatically uploaded through imgur are broken, and Gravatar ones are fine. Thanks for being my guinea pig :p

Comment: Thanks Mario appreciate the help so much 